# Strange behavior of Date Function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I encountered with this question today on StackOverflow but didn't get answer.

My question is

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2012-september-09')); // output - 2012-09-01

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('09-september-2012')); // output - 2012-09-09
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/TzyUp9NK)

I am confused that why the first format don't produce correct answer. Any Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

*if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed*.

Answer (score 4):

This is not behavior of the `date` function but of the `strtotime`. [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can handle only dates in specific formats listed on the [Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) manual page. `09-september-2012` is in the `dd ([ \t.-])* m ([ \t.-])* y` format listed there, but `2012-september-09` does not match any of the supported formats.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code,

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2012-september-09'));
```

`strtotime('2012-september-09')` is not a valid format **('2012-september-09')** for `strtotime()` date function.

refer this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php